# jQuery: using setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code with setInterval and setTimeout.

This seems to work every 6 seconds:

```
    var vasen = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
      vasen++;

      $('#valvonta').stop(true,true).css("left", vasen);

      var valvonta = 1;
      var kilpailu = 12;

      jQuery.post("ilmoittautuneet.php", {
        valvonta: valvonta,
        kilpailu: kilpailu
      }).done(function(data) {
      });
    }, 6000);
```

But this does not work every 6 seconds. It works only one time. What is the reason?

```
var vasen = 0;

(function valvonta() {
  vasen++;

  $('#valvonta').stop(true,true).css("left", vasen);

  var valvonta = 1;
  var kilpailu = 12;

  jQuery.post("ilmoittautuneet.php", {
    valvonta: valvonta,
    kilpailu: kilpailu
  }).done(function(data) {
  });
  setTimeout(valvonta, 6000);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies with the fact that you are **overwriting** what `valvonta` refers to in this line:

```
var valvonta = 1;
```

This means that `valvonta` will no longer refer to the function itself, but `1` instead. Therefore your function fails after the first run. To fix this issue, simply use another variable name:

```
var vasen = 0;

(function valvonta() {
  vasen++;

  $('#valvonta').stop(true,true).css("left", vasen);

  // Rename variables so they don't override `valvonta`
  var v = 1;
  var k = 12;

  jQuery.post("ilmoittautuneet.php", {
    valvonta: v,
    kilpailu: k
  }).done(function(data) {
  });

  setTimeout(valvonta, 6000);
})();
```

This solution, although functional, still makes it not very readable. What about simply calling a `setInterval` in the IIFE instead?

```
var vasen = 0;

(function () {
  // Declare function to be called recursively
  var valvonta = function() {
    vasen++;

    $('#valvonta').stop(true,true).css("left", vasen);

    // Rename variables so they don't override `valvonta`
    var v = 1;
    var k = 12;

    jQuery.post("ilmoittautuneet.php", {
      valvonta: v,
      kilpailu: k
    }).done(function(data) {
    });
  };

  // Recursively call function
  setInterval(valvonta, 6000);
})();
```

**Update:** I have a feeling that you might want to call the function *after* the `done` callback of your AJAX. If that is the case, you will need to rework the logic above:

```
var vasen = 0;

(function () {
  // Declare function to be called recursively
  var valvonta = function() {
    vasen++;

    $('#valvonta').stop(true,true).css("left", vasen);

    // Rename variables so they don't override `valvonta`
    var v = 1;
    var k = 12;

    // Store AJAX promise in variable
    var ajaxCall = jQuery.post("ilmoittautuneet.php", {
      valvonta: v,
      kilpailu: k
    });

    // When AJAX promise is resolved
    ajaxCall.done(function() {
        setTimeout(valvonta, 6000);
    });
  };

  // Call function for the first time
  valvonta();
})();
```

Comment: Do you mean that the problem is the fact that I have a function named as valvonta and a variable valvonta?

Comment: @xms Yes, that will be the root of your issue